# Using FormParams with Jersey and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee, jersey

Seems like this is an infrequently answered questions that's frequently asked. The documentation is somewhat ambiguous.

I want to post a set of parameters as described below. 
**Web service:**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response post(@FormParam("param") String param){
    // code..
}
```

**javascript:**

```
//var paramData = {"startDate":$("#startDate").val()};
var paramData = {startDate:$("#startDate").val()};
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'mysite.com/post',
    data: paramData,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    processData: false,
});
```

I've changed the contentType to false, tried serializing and stringfying the param data, etc. Either the argument comes in as null in the service or it returns an unsupported media type HTTP error code.

Answer (score 1):

### You are doing it wrong...

**1.** By default, your `contentType` will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so it's not necessary to specify it.

**2.** Why are you using `processData: false`? you should read the documentation from here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> processData (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in
>   to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
>   string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
>   to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If
>   you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.

**3.** Since `processData` is `true` by default and you don't need this to be `false` then it's not necessary to specify it.

**4.** You are just passing an `Object` as the `data` but where did you specify the `param` since that's the name that you used for your method? Take a look: `public Response post(@FormParam("param") String param)`

**5.** Since your `param` is a `String` you will need to convert your `Object` into a `queryString` *(same as if we were serializing a form)* and you can do it easily with `jQuery`, you should read the following: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

**6.**  So, at the end your code must look like this:

```
var data = {
    name: 'Oscar',
    lastname: 'Jara'
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'rest/service',
    data: {
        param: $.param(data)
    }
});
```

**7.** Now, if you print what your `param` variable contains inside your `REST` service, you will get this:

`name=Oscar&lastname=Jara`

Comment: For you example you should just use `data: $.param(data)`. And on the server use `@FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("lastName") String lastName`. Doesn't make much sense to put into one variable that you need to parse yourself, when the server will already do it for you.

Comment: @peeskillet Right, but that's what the OP currently have.

Comment: Yeah I notice that, but we should be promoting best practices, no? :-) I still gave you plus 1 though, for a well elaborated answer